# maven exec-maven-plugin: docker push not working

Tags: maven

I have following project structure:

```
myproj
|
|----pom.xml
|
|---module1
        |
        |---pom.xml  
|
|
|---module2
         |
         |
         |----pom.xml
         |----my-custom-artifact-1
             |----pom
             |----more modules
         |-----my-custom-artifact-2
            ....
```

pom at project root refers to modules modul1, module2.

module2 has its own child modules...my-custom-artifact-1,my-custom-artifact-2 and so on, which are responsible for generating artifacts.

module1's pom is doing this:

1. Copies artifacts generated by my-custom-artifact-1,my-custom-artifact-2 etc. to a target directory(say 'custom-artifacts') using plugin maven-dependency-plugin.
2. Then it uses another plugin exec-maven-plugin to generate docker image during install phase. This step involves copying artifacts from 'custom-artifacts' into the image.

All this works fine. Artifacts are generated, and populated into docker image.

I try to integrate few more executions to plugin exec-maven-plugin(in module1's pom) so as to login and push to docker registry:

```
<execution>
        <id>docker-login</id>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
        <executable>docker</executable>
        <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
        <arguments>
                <argument>login</argument>
                <argument>-u</argument>
                <argument>....</argument>
                <argument>-p</argument>
                <argument>....</argument>
                <argument>${docker.url}</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
<execution>
     <id>docker-push</id>
     <phase>deploy</phase>
     <goals>
      <goal>exec</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
        <executable>docker</executable>
        <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
        <arguments>
            <argument>push</argument>
                                <argument>${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</argument>
            </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

These new additions give error as:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy
> (injected-nexus-deploy) on project my-custom-artifact-1: Execution
> injected-nexus-deploy of goal
> org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy failed:
> Server credentials with ID "repository.apache.org" not found! -> [Help
> 1]

I can push same image if I run docker push command in isolation. But with maven it doesn't work.
I am not sure how 'repository.apache.org' comes into picture here.

PS: Building of those artifacts involves binary downloads from https://archive.apache.org/dist/nifi/. I don't think error is related to it, as docker image creation works perfectly fine.

Comment: To build/push a Docker image with maven I recommend using a specific plugin like https://dmp.fabric8.io/